# Group_by, and create new column with duration

Tags: r, dplyr

I have dataset, df,

```
  Subject      Folder      Message    Date
  A            Out                   9/9/2019 5:46:38 PM
  A            Out                   9/9/2019 5:46:40 PM
  A            Out                   9/9/2019 5:46:42 PM
  B            Out                   9/9/2019 5:48:00 PM
  B            Out                   9/9/2019 5:48:01 PM
  C            Out                   9/10/2019 5:49:01 PM
```

How do I group this by Subject, and then find the duration, while creating a new Duration column.
This is my desired output:

```
  Subject   Duration    Group
  A         4 sec      outdata1
  B         1 sec      outdata2
  C         0 sec      outdata3
```

Here is my dput:

```
         structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label =                 c("A", 
         "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Folder = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
         1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Out", class = "factor"), Message = c("", 
         "", "", "", "", ""), Date = structure(c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L
         ), .Label = c("9/10/2019 5:49:01 PM", "9/9/2019 5:46:38 PM", 
         "9/9/2019 5:46:40 PM", "9/9/2019 5:46:42 PM", "9/9/2019 5:48:00 PM", 
         "9/9/2019 5:48:01 PM"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
         -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is what I tried:

```
df %>%  
mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>% 
transmute(Subject, Duration = diff = difftime(as.POSIXct(Date, format = 
"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"),as.POSIXct(Date, 
format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p" ), units = "secs")) %>% 
ungroup %>% 
distinct %>% 
mutate(grp = str_c("Outdata", row_number()))
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Isn't this 4, 1, 0 `df %>% mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>% group_by(Subject) %>% summarise(Duration = diff(range(Date)))`

Comment: yes. let me correct. let me try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, we can use a group by 'Subject' before the `summarise` step

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>% 
   group_by(Subject) %>%
   summarise(Duration = diff(range(Date))) %>% 
   mutate(grp = str_c("Outdata", row_number()))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Subject Duration grp     
#  <fct>   <drtn>   <chr>   
#1 A       4 secs   Outdata1
#2 B       1 secs   Outdata2
#3 C       0 secs   Outdata3
```

If we need to control the `unit` use `difftime`

```
df %>%
    mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>%
    group_by(Subject) %>%
    summarise(Duration = difftime(max(Date), min(Date), unit = 'sec')) %>%
    mutate(grp = str_c("Outdata", row_number()))
```

Comment: This worked. thank you. I am using this as a workaround to my previous dilemma (something with my dataset) thank you! I will accept in 2 minutes

Comment: how do I set the output to only seconds? Where would the unit = "secs" go? I am not sure? After the date?

Comment: Hi @Akrun, is there  a way to incorporate a 'thresh' within this code? I have some datetimes within my data that is 9/10/2019 12:34:22 AM
9/10/2019 10:49:14 PM, so it is reflecting an inaccurate time duration. Could I add this within the code?   thresh <- duration(10, units = "minutes")
df %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(diff1 = Date - lag(Date)) %>%
 
  
 mutate(duration = if_else(diff1 < thresh1, diff1, NA_real_))

Comment: @TanishaHudson I guess you got the answer from the other poster's comment

Answer (score 2):

We can do this in base R :

```
df$Date <- as.POSIXct(df$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

transform(aggregate(Date~Subject, df, function(x) 
           difftime(max(x), min(x), units = "secs")), 
          Group = paste0('outdata', seq_along(Subject)))

#  Subject Date    Group
#1       A   4  outdata1
#2       B   1  outdata2
#3       C   0  outdata3
```

Comment: Ok thank you @Ronak, is there a way that a thresh can be added, say if the datetime behaves in this manner: 9/10/2019 12:34:22 AM
9/10/2019 10:49:14 PM , because my dataset is giving an inaccurate time duration when this happens. Could a thresh be added if the time exceeds 10 minutes?  
thresh3 <- duration(2, units = "minutes")

df %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy_hms(Date)) %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  mutate(diff1 = Date - lag(Date)) %>%    I am not sure how to incorporate this in the code above

Comment: I am wondering is there a way to add some type of 'break' in the duration if two consecutive datetimes exceed 10 minutes, then a new duration is created. I am still researching this.

Comment: depending on what you want to do you can use `difftime(Date, lag(date), units = "mins") > 10`

Comment: ok @Ronak like this: transform(aggregate(Date~Subject, df, function(x) 
           difftime(Date, lag(date), units = "mins") > 10,
          Group = paste0('outdata', seq_along(Subject)))         I am still learning, I am seeing how to incorporate into the code above